# How do I perform Pythonic simultaneous assignment when the source may be None?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I would like to perform the following simultaneous assignment in Python:

```
a, b = some_function()
```

However, for reasons beyond my control, `some_function` may return `None` instead of some `x, y`. If this happens I get the following error, because `None` cannot be simultaneously assigned to both `a` and `b`:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What is the Pythonic way to handle this situation? A `try` block, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a, b = some_function() or (None, None)
```

Beware, this would give `a, b = None, None` for every false-ish return value. But in your case that's not a problem, since non-empty tuples are always true-ish.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the return value in a single variable as tuple first, and then unpack it accordingly (You can assign a dummy tuple in case the return value is `None`):

```
tup = some_function()
a, b = tup if tup else (-1, -1)
```

I am not sure if it's the most pythonic way though.

Comment: yup, that crossed my mind and I thought it was a bit "look before you leap" rather than "duck typing", which prompted the question! what you've suggested is pretty succinct even if it turns out there isn't a PEP for it :)